# Queued ingestion in Kusto Python API

Tags: python, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am looking at the Kusto ingest API for Python and C#. C# clearly mentions 2 different types of ingest clients - Kusto**Queued**IngestClient and Kusto**Direct**IngestClient. However, I don't see those client types in Python. Python has 2 clients - KustoIngestClient and KustoStreamingIngestClient. Now which of these 2 clients in Python is Queued and which one is Direct?

Kusto .NET API documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-ingest

Answer (score 3):

The `KustoIngestClient` in the `azure-kusto-ingest` python library implements the *Queued ingestion* option, which is the recommended ingestion method for bulk ingestion in production workloads.

The `KustoStreamingIngestClient` in the same library implements *[Streaming ingestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-streaming)*

Direct ingestion isn't recommended for production workloads, but is included in the .NET client library, for low-volume testing purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Since the ingestion is queued, is there any way to check if the ingest message has been inserted into the queue? Since Queued ingestion tries retries on transient failures, I just want to make sure the ingest message is inserted into the queue. Is there any way to check that other than to make sure there are no exceptions thrown?

Comment: if the `ingest_from_*` method returns successfully, it means a message has been successfully placed in the queue. in addition, there's a code sample in the following link that can help you understand how to monitor the status of your queued ingestions (after they are successfully queued): https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-python/blob/4ba13e46f5ae6995786dd9a1d324df4b5b1b5a8c/azure-kusto-ingest/tests/sample.py#L97